# How to cause an Android Peripheral to initiate pairing a Bluetooth Low Energy connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

When developing an Android app that acts in the Peripheral role, how can the app initiate pairing / the connection to be bonded? (e.g. in the Central role can call [`createBond()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()))

Answer (score 0):

[Connect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html#connect(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20boolean)) from the BluetoothGattServer to a BluetoothDevice:

```
server.connect(device,false)
```